# Long time needed to read data from a csv file

Tags: r, csv

I should read a big CSV file (with more than 30000 rows and 10000 columns). Somehow I should read data column by column. This is my code:

```
con<-file("D:\\Data.csv","r")
datalist<-list()
for(spalte in 5:5)
{
  for(i in 1:20000)
  {

    line<-readLines(con,n=1,warn=FALSE)
    m<-list(as.integer(unlist(strsplit(line,split=","))))
    datalist<-c(datalist,sapply(m,"[[",spalte))

  }

}
```

but this code needs 4 minutes just to read only one column (in this example 5th column). How should I do to make this job faster?

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to read data line by line? Why?

Comment: If I am using `read.csv` method, I get an error about the size of the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't invent your own solution to well solved problems.  If `read.csv` is giving you out of memory errors, then:

1) Make sure that you are using 64-bit R (no 4GB RAM limit).

2) Ignore some rows that you don't need to save space.  The [`colbycol` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/colbycol/index.html) is useful for this.

3) Read the file into a database, and import what you need from there.  There are lots of solutions for this; start by reading answers to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1727772/134830).

4) Buy more RAM, or run your analysis on a remote workstation with more RAM (maybe a cloud server) or use an out-of-memory package.  See the [Task View on High Performance Computing](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html).

Comment: thank you but the problem is that I need all of data in csv file

Comment: There are lots of options; the best one depends on your setup.  Are you using 64-bit R?  How much RAM do you have on your machine?  Can you get or buy more?  Can you access a workstation with more RAM, or use a cloud compute service?  Do you have access to any databases that you can use as a staging area?  Are you really sure you need all 30k columns?

Comment: @Kaja Do you realise that this is approximately 2.2 Gb of data? It will not be easy, nor quick, to analyse this on a typical computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try fread(filename). It's in data.table package. It is very fast to read large files.

```
system.time(fread('abc.csv'))
user  system elapsed 
0.41    0.00    0.40 

system.time(read.csv('abc.csv'))
user  system elapsed 
2.28    0.02    2.29
```

If you are having memory issues then as Richie suggested use 64-bit and try to run on a server or you can even get Amazon EC2 machine with large RAM.

Comment: The problem is, that I dont have enough RAM

Comment: You can also try library("ff")
x<- read.csv.ffdf(file="file.csv", header=TRUE, VERBOSE=TRUE, first.rows=10000, next.rows=50000, colClasses=NA)